# Traversal directed graph with cycles

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, directed-graph

I wrote a script to construct a directed graph using networkx in python, and I want to get all possible path from start to end including cycles.
For example, there is a directed graph:
[image]

I want to get these paths:

A->B->D

A->B->C->D

A->B->C->B->D

A->B->C->B->C->B->D

...

As far as I know, there are many algorithms to find shortest paths or paths without cycles between 2 nodes, but I want to find paths with cycles.

Is there any algorithm to achieve this ?

Thx a lot

Comment: There's an infinity of such paths, do you have patience to wait for them all?

Comment: @n.m. Yes. I may use "yield" in python, then I can get path one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, there is an infinite number of such paths.

However, you can still generate all of them in a lazy way by maintaining all nodes `v` (and path you used to reach `v`) you can reach from the start node in `k` steps for `k=1,2,...`; if `v` is your target node, remember it.

When you have to return the next path, (i) pop the first target node off list, and (ii) generate the next candidates for all non-target nodes on the list. If there is no target node on the list, repeat (ii) until you find one.

The method works assuming the path always exists. If you don't find a path in `n-1` steps, where `n` is the number of nodes, simply report that no path exists.

Here's the pseudo code for an algorithm that generates paths from shortest to longest *assuming unit weights*:

```
class Node {
    int steps
    Node prev

    Node(int steps=0, Node prev=null) {
        prev = prev
        steps = steps
    }
}

class PathGenerator {
    Queue<Node> nodes
    Node start, target;

    PathGenerator(Node start, Node target) {
        start = start
        target = target

        nodes = new Queue<>()
        nodes.add(start) // assume start.steps=0 and stat.prev=null
    }

    Node nextPath(int n) {
        current_length = -1;
        do {
            node = nodes.poll()
            current_length = node.steps
            // expand to all others you can reach from node
            for each u in node.neighbors()
                list.add(new Node(node, node.steps+1))
            // if node is the target, return the path
            if (node == target)
                return node
        } while (current_length < n);
       throw new Exception("no path of length <=n exists");
    }
}
```

Beware that the list `nodes` can grow exponentially in the worst case (think of what happens in case you run it on a complete graph).